# Copy configurations/migrate from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, migration

I am working on migrating more than 20 websites from IIS 6.0 to Windows 2008 server/IIS 7.0. All these websites have their own IIS configurations and settings. Wanted to know, if there is any way by which I can read my IIS 6.0 configurations for each and every website and set the same/equivalent configurations on IIS 7.0?

I want to avoid using manual compare and paste stuff over here.

Comment: Ok, i am now trying to use Web Deploy Tool. But I am not sure what command I should use to copy the configuration from Server1(IIS 6.0) to Server2(IIS 7.0).

can anybody please help me out? :(

Answer (score 0):

I finally did this using the Web deploy Tool.

Thanks everybody